# How to get the string before "_" in PHP

Tags: php, substring, php-7

I need to get the string before `_`, but what I've tried is not working properly. The following is a list of input values stored in `$b` var:

```
vendor_code
vendor_name
hotel_name_0
hotel_room_type_0
hotel_in_date_0
...
vendor_code
vendor_name
hotel_name_N
hotel_room_type_N
hotel_in_date_N
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$a = [
    'vendor_code',
    'vendor_name',
    'hotel_name_0',
    'hotel_room_type_0',
    'hotel_in_date_0'
];

foreach ($a as $b) {
    echo substr($b, 0, -(strlen(strrchr($b, '_')))), PHP_EOL;
}
```

The code works almost perfectly, but for those, where you have not the ending `_N` it fails, because it is removing part of the original string (see the output below).

```
vendor 
vendor 
hotel_name 
hotel_room_type 
hotel_in_date
```

A valid output should be as follow:

```
vendor_code
vendor_name
hotel_name 
hotel_room_type 
hotel_in_date
```

This means, I need to remove all the content after the last `_N`.

Can any give me some advice here?

Comment: Please clarify; which `_` needs to be the separation mark?  For example, should `hotel_in_date_0` return `hotel_in_date` with `0` being removed, or should it return `hotel`, `in`, `date`, `0`, etc.

Comment: @RobertC I've added the information to the OP as valid output and what I want to remove

Comment: Is `_N` always a number?

Comment: @AlexanderGuz yes, `N` should be always a number but just to be sure I can run a check on it if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the ending part `_N`(if occurs) using `preg_replace` function:

```
...
foreach ($a as $word) {
    echo preg_replace("/_\d+$/", "", $word). PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Like the solution. I suggested to use `preg_match`, but this one is shorter.

Comment: Yeah I liked too this is why I accepted this instead yours, but you get a vote too :)

Comment: Comparing all 3 regex's that do the same thing, this one is the most efficient and absolute as it will only match the ending digit.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
<?php

$a = [
    'vendor_code',
    'vendor_name',
    'hotel_name_0',
    'hotel_room_type_0',
    'hotel_in_date_0'
];

foreach ($a as $b) {
    $hasMatch = preg_match('/(.*)_\d+/', $b, $matches);
    if ($hasMatch) {
        echo $matches[1] . PHP_EOL;    
    } else {
        echo $b . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
vendor_code
vendor_name
hotel_name
hotel_room_type
hotel_in_date
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regex to solve the situation:

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
    if(preg_match('/(.*)(?:_\d)/', $b, $match)){
        echo "'$b' is a match and should be {$match[1]}\n";
    } else {
        echo "'$b' does not need a modification\n";
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
>     'vendor_code' does not need a modification
>     'vendor_name' does not need a modification
>     'hotel_name_0' is a match and should be hotel_name
>     'hotel_room_type_0' is a match and should be hotel_room_type
>     'hotel_in_date_0' is a match and should be hotel_in_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the following:

```
$a = [
    'vendor_code',
    'vendor_name',
    'hotel_name_0',
    'hotel_room_type_0',
    'hotel_in_date_0'
];

$data = [];

foreach($a as $key) {
    $temp = explode('_', $key);
    if (is_numeric($temp[count($temp) - 1])) {
        unset($temp[count($temp) - 1]);
        $data[] = implode('_', $temp);
    } else {
        $data[] = $key;
    }
}

var_dump($data);
```

Result:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'vendor_code' (length=11)
  1 => string 'vendor_name' (length=11)
  2 => string 'hotel_name' (length=10)
  3 => string 'hotel_room_type' (length=15)
  4 => string 'hotel_in_date' (length=13)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that:

```
foreach ($a as $b) {
    list($first, $second) = explode('_', $b, 2);
    echo implode(' ', [$first, $second, PHP_EOL]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't output the expected output.

Comment: This may work in this situation, but it's very inflexible.